# PostgreSQL - How do I cancel what I am typing in psql terminal if I make a typo?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am just getting started with SQL, and while I work I am making a lot of typos.  For instance, after running `psql mydatabase`, I tried to make a table -

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE table_name (
postgres=(# _id serial PRIMARY KEY
postgres=(# name VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
postgres=(#
```

and at that point, I realize that I forgot a comma after `PRIMARY KEY`.  How do I just cancel everything that I am typing and start the command from scratch?  I couldn't find any answers via Google or StackOverflow, despite this surely being a common problem.. Do I just type `ABORT;` or is that something completely different? Working from Windows PowerShell, if that makes any difference.

EDIT: I checked the commands and apparently you can type \r and press enter to reset the query buffer.  Keeping this posted for other newbies

Comment: Ctrl+c should do the trick. Or you could try adding a ; and hitting enter. The badly formed SQL will not get executed. \e will bring up a text editor. Use that for going back / forth as you construct you statement

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to get out is to send a SIGINT signal to psql, typically by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (unless you configured your terminal differently).

Unless you are stuck in a string (prompt ends in `='#` or `='>`), you can also use `\r` to reset the query buffer.

If desperate, you can also quit `psql` with `\q` and restart it.

Comment: Ctrl+C kills the shell: `Session terminated, killing shell...d ...killed.`

Comment: @rostamiani Strange setup or operating system...

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu 20.10 and 21.10 without any config changes. and on several Ubuntu servers. All the same. I will quit `psql`. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: You'd have to change your terminal setup - but alternatively, you can try `\r`, as in my extended answer.